# When concurrent filing, can an I-485 be filed online and if so do you do it from the same USCIS account used to file the I-130?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, concurrent-i130-i485

I am a US Citizen. I have an account with USCIS that I used to file the I-130 for my marriage to my wife. Do I file the I-485 (Green Card application / Permanent Resident) on my USCIS account to do concurrent filing, or does she file it on her USCIS account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I-485 can not be filed online at all, from the USCIS Emma bot.

> Form I-130 can be filed online where you can print your receipt and have your relative **submit the receipt with their paper Form I-485 and all supporting documents by mail** or you can file both paper forms together by mail with all supporting documents..

So you have to file I-130 online, print a receipt and mail it together with your I-485. But if you're going to that you should also file you're I-765 (work authorization) and I-131 Travel Document too, because it's free.

> Filing Forms I-765 and I-131 with Form I-485
>
> **If you submit Form I-485 and pay the required fee, you do not have to pay an additional fee to also file Form I-765, Application for Employment Authorization, and/or Form I-131, Application for Travel Document**, for advance parole. **You may submit these forms together**. If you choose not to file Form I-765 and/or Form I-131 with your Form I-485, then you must submit a copy of your I-797C, Notice of Action, (also known as your receipt) as evidence that you filed Form I-485.

For more information see this page.

- https://www.uscis.gov/i-485