# If I filed my I-130 months ago but it's not yet processed is too late to concurrently file an I-485?

Tags: usa, immigration, concurrent-i130-i485

The I-485 can under certain circumstance be "concurrently filed" with an I-130 regardless of [whether or not you filed the I-130 online](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/23914/13797). [If the I-130 still has not been processed, currently the process time is estimated at 11.5 months,](https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/), can you *still* concurrently file the I-485? Does it matter if it's been six months since you filed the I-130 if it has **NOT** yet been processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If it's still pending, it's not too late.

If a visa number is immediately available for your category and priority date this month, you can file I-485 while your I-130 is still pending. You need to include a copy of your I-130 receipt with your I-485.

Comment: Cool: never too late if it "is still pending" makes perfect sense. Not sure what this means _"if a visa number is immediately available for your category"_. My wife didn't need a visa though, she was already in the US.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: The Immediate Relative category (spouse, parent, or unmarried under-21 child of US citizen) has unlimited visa numbers and is always available. Other categories have annual numerical limitations. Beneficiaries can only immigrate (through either Consular Processing or Adjustment of Status) if their petition was filed before the date on that month's [visa bulletin](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin.html) for the beneficiary's country of birth

Comment: Thanks that make sense!